# It's beautiful! You ................ given me a nicer present. (Wouldn't have - couldn't have ) choose the right one

Tags: modal-verbs

I feel confused about the choices.
I think you wouldn't have given me is the right one as if it it the nicest present you've ever given me. Others say it's couldn't have given is right as an expression.
Can anyone help???

Comment: It's always 'couldn't have'. You couldn't have given me a nicer present. He couldn't have made a better speech. It couldn't have been a nicer day. The idea is that it is impossible for the thing to be any better because it is at maximum goodness.

Comment: It works for bad things too. You couldn't have made a worse choice of husband (he's a drunkard, a thief, and a fascist).

Comment: @Azza,  you may think that Michael has given you enough in the comments for you to write your own answer in the box below.  If you think you can, please write your own answer.

Comment: I knew that ot is 'couldn't have given', but my question is when my learners argue, they make me believe it' s still logic to choose wouldn't have given.

Comment: "You wouldn't have given me a nicer present" is insulting. It would be used if someone gives you a bad present but claims "Oh I was going to get you something good but the shop was shut", and you tell them that they never give nice presents (or never give presents that are as nice as those that someone else gives).